# How can I capture a SQL Stored Procedure Error triggered by RAISEERROR() in .asmx file?

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures, asmx, raiseerror

I'm **very** new to .NET. All I've done so far is implement some SQL Stored Procedure calls as WebServices by copying and pasting existing code (as instructed by my superior).

I am calling some commands via `Database.ExecuteNonQuery()`. In the SQL Stored Procedure, I am performing some security checks based on the LoginId passed in (a user can only edit items of which they are the owner). If the security check fails, I am calling RAISEERROR() to trigger an error, but my .asmx file is not seeing this as an exception, and simply exits the Stored Procedure.

My asmx file:

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument UpdateSomeItem(Int32 ItemIdNmb, String Foo)
{
    try
    {

        // Create the Database object, using the default database service. The
        // default database service is determined through configuration.
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        DbParameter param;

        string sqlCommand = "updateSomeItem";
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(sqlCommand);

        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "ItemIdNmb", DbType.Int32, ItemIdNmb);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Foo", DbType.String, Foo);
        db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "UpdateLoginIdNmb", DbType.Int32, SessionLoginIdNmb);

        #region Return Parameter
        param = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "Return";
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        param.DbType = DbType.Int32;

        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        #endregion

        // Execute the Command
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);

        myDataSet = new DataSet();

        myDataSet.DataSetName = "DataSet";
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(errorDataTable);

        statusDataRow["Status"] = "Success";
        statusDataTable.Rows.Add(statusDataRow);
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(statusDataTable);

        returncodeDataRow["ReturnCode"] = dbCommand.Parameters["Return"].Value;
        returncodeDataTable.Rows.Add(returncodeDataRow);
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(returncodeDataTable);

        xmlReturnDoc.LoadXml(myDataSet.GetXml());

        return xmlReturnDoc;
    }
    // THIS IS WHERE I WANT MY RAISE ERROR TO GO
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        return ReturnClientError(e, "someerror");
    }
}
```

My SQL Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateSomeItem
(
    @ItemIdNmb             INT,
    @Foo                   VARCHAR(100),
    @UpdateLoginIdNmb      INT
)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

/* If the user performing the action did not create the Item in question, 
    raise an error. */
IF NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Items
    WHERE IdNmb = @ItemIdNmb
        AND LoginIdNmb = @UpdateLoginIdNmb
    )
    RAISERROR (
        'User action not allowed - User is not the owner of the specified Item', 
        10, 
        1)

UPDATE Items
SET Foo = @Foo
WHERE IdNmb = @ItemIdNmb

RETURN 0

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my Stored Procedure with the following:

```
/* If the user performing the action did not create the Item in question, 
    return a code other than 0. */
IF NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Items
    WHERE IdNmb = @ItemIdNmb
        AND LoginIdNmb = @UpdateLoginIdNmb
    )
    RETURN 1
```

And I handle in my .asmx file like this:

```
int returnValue = (int)dbCommand.Parameters["Return"].Value;

if (returnValue == 0)
    statusDataRow["Status"] = "Success";
/* Stored Procedure will return a value of "1" if the user is 
    attempting to update an Item that they do not own. */
else
    statusDataRow["Status"] = "Error";

statusDataTable.Rows.Add(statusDataRow);
myDataSet.Tables.Add(statusDataTable);

returncodeDataRow["ReturnCode"] = dbCommand.Parameters["Return"].Value;
returncodeDataTable.Rows.Add(returncodeDataRow);
myDataSet.Tables.Add(returncodeDataTable);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Error Severity it too low. Severities 1 - 10 are treated as information messages and do not break the flow of a C# app.

A more thorough explanation can be found in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963379/storing-sqlservers-raiserror-message-in-c/963409#963409) from [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105929/remus-rusanu).

Comment: Thanks @ahsteele. This makes sense. I changed my logic to return a different code under the condition I described, and to handle the Return Code in my C# (see below).