# Custom Errors in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, raiserror

Most of the discussions online regarding SQL Server's error handling seem to be focus on how to gracefully handle errors thrown by the processing of T-SQL, using THROW, or TRY...CATCH, and so on.

What I have is a Stored Procedure which accepts several parameters.  A couple of those parameters must only have values within a certain range, so at the start of my procedure I want to check the values that have been passed from the application (ASP.NET) and return an error if they aren't within the acceptable boundaries.

At the moment I've got:

```
IF @RequesterType <> 2 AND @RequesterType <> 3
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('The value for RequesterType must be either 2 (Client) or 3 (Representative)', 10, 1)
    RETURN;
END
```

When I execute the procedure that contains this code from within SSMS and pass a value other than 2 or 3, sure enough the message I've specified gets displayed.  But it doesn't seem... severe enough.  It doesn't seem apparent that an actual error has occurred.

I know it's possible to specify the severity parameter of the RAISERROR statement, but unless I'm going to make it very high (>19, I believe), indicating a fatal system error, I don't think that's going to make much difference.

I'm just wondering whether, with the code I've got, when the web application calls this procedure, it'll actually know that there's been a error.  Would the VB.NET code calling the procedure know that an error has been thrown?  If not, how could I re-write my procedure so that it would?  I'm sure there's a best-practice way of doing this, but at the moment I feel like I'm trying to hack it.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: It should  be fine if your error level is above >= 10 which will result in an exception - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963379/storing-sqlservers-raiserror-message-in-c-sharp (duplicate, perhaps?)

Comment: To add to @dotnetnate's comment, if you have no control over the VB.net code, there's not much you can do.  The VB developer has the responsibility to handle the exception appropriately.  Your proc validates parameter values and sends an exception (via `RAISERROR`) back to the web app, if necessary.  I'd say you've done your part.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Not quite a duplicate question, I don't think, as I was confident that I was passing the error message back to the application, just not sure that it was being passed back as an actual error that would need handling rather than just information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use RAISERROR having security level 16. According to http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html this value represents: "16 – Miscellaneous User Error".

Example:

```
PRINT 'Test #1'
RAISERROR('First bla, bla, bla', 10, 1)
PRINT 'Test #2'
RAISERROR('Second bla, bla, bla', 16, 1)
```

Output:

```
Test #1
First bla, bla, bla
Test #2
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Second bla, bla, bla
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I came across that article and started reading it but in the introduction it mentions that it's written for SQL Server 2000 and that newer versions have more sophisticated error handling, so I stopped there and moved on.  Read several other articles, including Microsoft's own article on RAISERROR, which didn't actually list the various severity values and their meanings.